# List view not displaying

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-listview

Hi i have created a android app which displays the data from a mysql db in the form of a list.

This is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    

        // URL to the JSON data         
        String strUrl = "http://192.168.2.3/Flutura/PHP/Core/Data/android.data.php";

        // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data 
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Starting the download process
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

        // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);


    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
        }

        return data;
    }



    /** AsyncTask to download json data */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        String data = null;
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
                        try{
                            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                        }
                        return data;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                        // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread 
                        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

                        // Start parsing xml data
                        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);                        

                }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

        JSONObject jObject;
        // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread 
        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();
                countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
            }

            // Instantiating json parser class
            CountryJSONParser countryJsonParser = new CountryJSONParser();

            // A list object to store the parsed countries list
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

            try{
                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }          

            // Keys used in Hashmap 
            String[] from = { "outlet_id","outlet_name","lat","lng","outlet_location"};

            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.tv_country,R.id.iv_flag,R.id.tv_country_details};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item         
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.lv_layout, from, to);  

            return adapter;
        }

       /* /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed 
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

            // Setting adapter for the listview
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

          /*  for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                //ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);

                // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview 
                //imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
            }   
        }       
    }*/
  /*  
    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView 
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream=null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url                
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory 
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image 
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");               

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);             

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);              

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                //Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();             

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position",position);              

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                return hmBitmap;                


            }catch (Exception e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
*/      
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            //String path = (String) result.get("flag");            

            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            //int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

            // Getting adapter of the listview
            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
            //HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position); 

            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter 
            //hm.put("flag",path);

            // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

This is the class where i user JSONParser to parse the data.

```
/** A class to parse json data */
public class CountryJSONParser {

    // Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
    public List<HashMap<String,Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

        JSONArray jCountries = null;
        try {       
            // Retrieves all the elements in the 'countries' array 
            jCountries = jObject.getJSONArray("countries");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         // Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
         // where each json object represent a country
        return getCountries(jCountries);
    }


    private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCountries(JSONArray jCountries){
        int countryCount = jCountries.length();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> country = null; 

        // Taking each country, parses and adds to list object 
        for(int i=0; i<countryCount;i++){
            try {
                // Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country 
                country = getCountry((JSONObject)jCountries.get(i));
                countryList.add(country);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return countryList;
    }

    // Parsing the Country JSON object 
    private HashMap<String, Object> getCountry(JSONObject jCountry){

        HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String countryName = "";
        String flag="";
        String language = "";
        String capital = "";
        String location = "";
        //String currencyCode = "";
        //String currencyName = "";     

        try {
            countryName = jCountry.getString("outlet_id");
            flag = jCountry.getString("outlet_name");
            language = jCountry.getString("lat");
            capital = jCountry.getString("lng");
            location = jCountry.getString("outlet_location");
            //currencyCode = jCountry.getJSONObject("outlet_image").getString("outlet_image");
            //currencyName = jCountry.getJSONObject("outlet_location").getString("outlet_location");

            String details =        "Language : " + language + "\n" +
                    "Capital : " + capital + "\n" ;
                   // "Currency : " + currencyName + "(" + currencyCode + ")";

            country.put("country", countryName);
            //country.put("flag", R.drawable.blank);
            country.put("flag_path", flag);
            country.put("details", details);

        } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return country;
    }
}
```

My problem is that the list view is not displaying. Please Help.

Comment: you never perform the setAdapter call on the ListView instance

Comment: can you tell me how to do that this code also retrieves the image but i dnt want to print the image so remover the code which downloads the image.Tell me where i went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is much messy code and most important think is that you never call `setAdapter` on your `ListView`. Do it and it should works.

Also my suggestion is that your first create and initialise `ListView` instance and also set `Adapter` for `ListView` with empty `List`. Create subclass of `BaseAdapter` to get more control over `Adapter` and pass `List` via constructor:

```
public MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   public MyAdapter(Context c, int layout, List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries) {

   }

   // implement methods as getItem, getItemId, ...


   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      if (convertView == null) {
          // inflate row, use RowHolder design pattern to hold data of each row in
          // wrapping object like RowHolder and set it as tag to convertView
      }
      else {
        //get existing tag from convertView
      }
      if (!countries.isEmpty()) {
        // set data to elements in row

      }
   }
}
```

And in your `AsyncWorker` when you download some item from Server, add it to `List` and call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter`.

Here is example: [**`Android ListView`**](http://www.javasrilankansupport.com/2012/05/android-listview-example-with-image-and.html).

Comment: in `onPostExecute()` method in `ListViewLoaderTask` class.

Comment: Thank you very much but the above link also downloads the images which i dont want to can you tell me which part in the code to comment and which part to keep?

Comment: no i dont want to download the images only the text and address which i have stored in the db

Comment: In your ListViewLoaderTask class you dowload data and set them into Adapter so in onPostExecute method of ListViewLoaderTask class that takes parameter SimpleAdapter so call setAdapter method on your List and it should works.

Comment: i wrote that you won't(will not) download images, its only example how to do it.

Comment: just uncomment this: `protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);}`

Answer (score 0):

In the `OnPostExecute` of the `ListViewLoaderTask` add `mListView.setAdapter(adapter);`

On the other hand, you are not doing anything with the result. You just call

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = mListView.getAdapter();
```

and then set it back to the list view. This do basically nothing. You must populate the adapter with the retrieved data.